# How can I change Menu item size in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I created a simple menu item with the help of ActionBarSherlock:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, ITEMD, 0, "item").setIcon(R.drawable.topbar_btn_inbox).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.breadcrumb_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But I can't change its width and height. How can I do this in XML or programatically?

Comment: Although I have yet to use ActionBarSherlock, I'm guessing the answer is the same as for the standard ActionBar: You can't. The height of the ActionBar is standard across all applications, and the width of each button is set to the width of the content. If you want more customization, you will likely have to create your own version of the ActionBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tanis.7x stated and according to the [Action Bar Icons Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html) size and densities for different devices are already predefined for consistency, so you cant change any. However you can define your custom Action Bar view and then behave like a view and change sizes, etc:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
actionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view);
```